# 「InputFiled」で半角英数字のみ入力を許可したい

Tags: unity3d

「InputFiled」で半角英数字のみ入力を許可したく、
Content Typeを「Alphanumeric」にしているのですが、
文字種の選択が「あA1」と表示されてしまいます。
（確認したAndroidのバージョンは6です）
「あ(日本語入力)」の状態でも、英語しか入力できないのですが、
そもそも、文字種の選択を「A1」だけにしたいです。
どのような設定にすれば良いのかご教示をお願いします。

Unityバージョン：2017.4.3f1 (64-bit)

Comment: マルチポスト　https://okwave.jp/qa/q9510323.html